# "Show Users" from MongoDB in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to list all the users who have access to a MongoDB, but via PHP.  Basically the same as if you were do the following from the mongo shell:

```
> use test
switched to db test
> show users
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51f74b1c9d8036288ae01e98"),
        "user" : "admin",
        "pwd" : "cc4fa5214a55925052f2892be6feb470",
        "roles" : [
                "readWrite",
                "dbAdmin"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52085c1dc9f60326cb20cb37"),
        "user" : "user_name",
        "pwd" : "ec416be9a5e17fbe48a7ceb93e63ecba",
        "roles" : [
                "readWrite",
                "dbAdmin"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52085c35c9f60326cb20cb38"),
        "user" : "test_user",
        "pwd" : "bf7a0adf9822a3379d6dfb1ebd38b92e",
        "roles" : [
                "readWrite"
        ]
}
```

I have tried using the execute command builtin to PHP without any luck.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `system.users` collection I believe ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/ ) like so:

```
foreach($db->selectCollection('system.users')->find() as $user)
    var_dump($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only showing the first user.  Not listing all of them.  For example:

```
$db_name = "test"
echo "Database Name: $db_name <br />";
foreach($conn->$db_name->selectCollection('system.users')->find() as $users);
var_dump($users);
```

Outputs

```
Database Name: test <br />
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 52085c35c9f60326cb20cb38
        )

    [user] => test_user
    [pwd] => bf7a0adf9822a3379d6dfb1ebd38b92e
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => readWrite
        )

)
```

Instead of all the users on the database.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever I had to break out the command more.  This works great:

```
$users = $conn->$db_name->selectCollection('system.users')->find();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    var_dump($user);
}
```